# Is this git branch local or remote?

Tags: git, git-remote

I've setup my USB stick as a remote. Now, when I do `git branch` I get the following:

```
dev/app/menus
master
usb/dev/app/banner
usb/dev/app/menus
```

How do I access `usb/dev/app/banner`?

Do I need to pull or fetch it first?

And is this now local or remote? (i.e. if I pulled out the USB stick could I merge that code).

Comment: `git branch` doesn't show remotes without the `-a` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`usb/dev/app/banner` is local, you can run the usual `checkout` on it even if you have no connection to the remote (your USB stick is elsewhere).

In order to make the local branch `usb/dev/app/banner` up to date with what is on your USB stick, use `fetch`:

```
git fetch usb dev/app/banner
```

This will get the latest commits from your remote `usb`, branch `dev/app/banner`, and make them accessible through `usb/dev/app/banner` and `FETCH_HEAD` locally. You can unplug the USB stick, the commits are here. You can merge `usb/dev/app/banner` wherever you want.

---

Additional info:

If you want to get the latest commits from your remote and continue working from there, I would recommend creating a local branch:

```
git fetch usb dev/app/banner
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
git checkout -b dev/app/banner
```

It would not make sense to work in `usb/dev/app/banner` (remote branch), you should let that reflect the state of the remote, and work in the local `dev/app/banner` instead. I am not sure if commiting to `usb/dev/app/banner` is even possible.

Fetching a remote branch, checking it out, and creating a local branch from it is a rather common scenario (the three commands above) so there is a short hand version:

```
git fetch usb dev/app/banner:<local_branch_name>
```

I usually use the same name for `<local_branch_name>` as in the remote repo, so that I locally have:

- `usb/dev/app/banner`: the remote branch, a mirror of what is on the USB stick,
- `dev/app/banner`: the local branch, in which I commit.

When you have commits ready to be published in `dev/app/banner`, you push to your USB stick:

```
git push usb dev/app/banner
```

(first you need to get the latest changes that may be on the USB stick but not on your local repo yet)

Answer (score 1):

You can just access it like you would any other branch.

```
git checkout usb/dev/app/banner
```

By default, `git branch` will not show any remote branches.  If you wanted to see only remote branches, you'd have to add the `-r` flag to the command.